# Running mapped java method with listen to SWT Browser changes

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, swing, swt

I used SWT Eclipse browser in Java project.

I created test page as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Start: <input type="text" id="startTimeField" onchange="setTime();fieldChanged();" placeholder="Type text and press Enter"> ms

<script>
    function setTime() {
        document.getElementById('startTimeField').value = new Date().getMilliseconds();
     }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`onchange="setTime();fieldChanged();"` it means Javascript method calls. `setTime()` is on page, `fieldChanged()` is mapped in Java code.

Mapped javascript function - `fieldChanged()` in java as below:

```
private void startListen() {
    SWTRunner.runInSwtThread(() -> new BrowserFunction(getSwtBrowser().getBrowser(), "fieldChanged") {
                @Override
                public Object function(Object[] objects) {
                    swtResultField.setText("" + new Date().getTime() % 1000);
                    return null;
                }
            });
}
```

I have problem on which Thread I should run the mapped function in java code ? 
I try as in code above - run it in `SWTRunner.runInSwtThread()` and on OS X system it works well, but on Windows system return `SWTException: Invalid thread access` on line `new BrowserFunction(...)`.

On which thread I should run mapped function in Java to avoid the exception in Windows system?

**EDIT**

As @greg-449 says I edited and call the method but also get error on Windows system, the method looks like:

```
private void startListen() {
        new BrowserFunction(getSwtBrowser().getBrowser(), "fieldChanged") {
            @Override
            public Object function(Object[] objects) {
                getSwtBrowser().getBrowser().getDisplay.asyncExec(() -> swtResultField.setText("" + new Date().getTime() % 1000));
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

SWTException is thrown on `new BrowserFunction(..)` line

Comment: You need to update this question to make it clear that most of your code is Swing not SWT.

Comment: But problem is about how to register the `BrowserFunction()` named `fieldChanged()` in JavaScript and listen to it. Problem is with threads.

Comment: No, the problem is that you are mixing Swing and SWT which makes the thread problem much worse. An answer which applies to pure SWT code does not work with Swing + SWT.

Comment: @greg-449 It works on OS X Sierra system using `SWTRunner.runInSwtThread()` but why the same solution on Windows made problem ? I want to solve it for Windows operating system.

Comment: The internals of the SWT code are completely different on each Platform. Incorrect code that seems to work on one platform will fail on another.

Comment: OK I understand, so what You suggest to do ? I must listen browser changes in java code.

Comment: @greg-449 Your solution works for Windows. Please create answer and I will accept it. I must do IF statement to check when is OSX and when Windows. On OSX I need to use `SWTRunner.runInSwtThread()` and on Windows I need to use `Display.asyncExec()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Problem is with Thread depend of operating system.

On Windows must be run on `Display.asyncExec()`.

On OS X must be run on `SWTRunner.runInSwtThread()`.